# Find an estimate for $p=P(X\geqq 20)$

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation, parameter-estimation

I have this problem I'm stuck with. I would really appreciate some help.

> "The following is a sample from a normal distribution.
>
> $7.6 , 9.6, 10.4, 10.7, 11.9, 14.1, 14.6, 18.5$
>
> a) Let $X$ have this normal distribution and let $p=P(X\geqq 20)$. If
>   we estimate $p$ by the relative frequency, we just get 0. Suggest
>   another estimate.
>
> b)Let $x$ be the 95th percentil, i.e. a value such that $P(X \leqq x)
> > = 0.95$. Suggest an estimate for $x$."

This seems fairly straight forward. I dont get the same answer as my text book however. I'm thinking since $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma ^2)$ we can estimate $\mu = \bar{X} = 12.175$, and $\sigma ^2 = s^2 =\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(X_k-\bar{X})^2 \approx 11.79 \implies s \approx 3.43$. So far so good.

Now $p = P(X\geqq 20) = 1- P(\frac{X-\bar{X}}{s}\leqq\frac{20-\bar{X}}{s})$ where $\frac{X-\bar{X}}{s} \sim F_{t_6}(0,1)$, i.e. a T-distribution of $n-2 = 8-2 = 6$ degrees of freedom. (This is where I'm uncertain whether this is correct).

This leads to $p = 1-F_{t_6}(2.28)$ which gives the wrong answer according to the book. In the same way does the (b)-part go wrong as well. The main question is how to use the T-distribution correctly. Is the T-distribution even the right choice in this problem?

I would very much appreciate some help because my text book dont explain this types of problems very well.

Cheers!

Comment: If $(\hat\mu,\hat\sigma)$ is the estimate of $(\mu,\sigma)$, then the estimated probability is simply $$p=1-P(X<20)=1-P\left(\frac{X-\hat\mu}{\hat\sigma}<\frac{20-\hat\mu}{\hat\sigma}\right)=1-\Phi\left(\frac{20-\hat\mu}{\hat\sigma}\right)$$

Not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes ok. Thanks for your answer. I have been told that when using the estimate $s^2$ instead of $\sigma ^2$ we should always look at the T distribution instead. And I have also been told that the number of "degrees of freedom" is the sample size $n$ minus the number of parameters beeing estimated.

Comment: If you are looking to find the value of $p$, then it equals $1-\Phi\left(\frac{20-12.175}{3.43}\right)$ which can be found using tables.

Comment: Ok. Im not sure why we can use the Z-table however, since we estimate the variance with $s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(X_k-\bar{X})^2$. I thought that you were supposed to use the T-distribution when the sample size $n$ is small and you estimate the variance with $s^2$

Comment: The only relation here to the $t$ distribution I know is that, given $\mu$, the statistic $\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar X-\mu)}{s}$ is distributed as $t_{n-1}$. I don't see how this is useful when estimating a probability using method of moments estimates.

Comment: My answer below is based on a guess at what the question is looking for. If it's not right, maybe you can show the answer book value and one of us can work backwards from that to figure out the actual question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Estimating a probability.** My guess is that you are supposed to estimate $\mu$ as $\hat\mu = \bar X = 12.175$ and $\sigma$ as $\hat \sigma = 3.434.$ Then use the estimated distribution
$X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\hat \mu, \hat\sigma)$ to estimate $P(X \ge 20) \approx
0.01135.$ In R statistical software (where `pnorm` is a normal CDF), it looks like this:

```
x=c(7.6,9.6,10.4,10.7,11.9,14.1,14.6,18.5)
mean(x); sd(x)
[1] 12.175
[1] 3.434177
1 - pnorm(20, mean(x), sd(x))
[1] 0.01134643
```

Here is a look at the quantile method suggested in part (b). According to R,
the 95th percentile of your data is about 17.1. (Various texts and software
programs have various rules for finding quantiles of small datasets. The
'percentile rule' in your book may give a somewhat different answer--presumably somewhere
between 14.6 and 18.5.).

```
sort(x)
[1]  7.6  9.6 10.4 10.7 11.9 14.1 14.6 18.5
quantile(x, .95)
   95% 
17.135
```

If we look for the 95th percentile of the estimated normal distribution, $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=12.175,\sigma=3.434)$ from above,
the answer is not a lot different: about 17.82. (Percentiles of
continuous distributions are precisely defined, so there is no quibbling
here, except for rounding.)

```
qnorm(.95, mean(x), sd(x))
[1] 17.82372
```

---

Having shown you this much, the following may be beyond the point. But it was
reasonable for you to think of using a t distribution for *something* in part (a),
and I want to finish that part of the story. Read as much as interests you.

Also, I have to say that
using only $n = 8$ observations in this way to 'find' $P(X \ge 20)$ from a 
normal distribution with unknown $\mu$ and $\sigma$ is simply not a workable
idea in practice. As you will see from the confidence intervals (CIs) below,
there is a lot of room for random error in estimating $\mu$ and $\sigma$
from only $n=8$ observations.

**Estimating the population mean:** The t distribution would be appropriate if you were finding a confidence
interval based on $\bar X$ for the normal population mean $\mu$ or testing
a null hypothesis about $\mu.$

Specifically,
the `t.test` procedure in R uses Student's t distribution
with $n - 1 = 8 - 1 = 7$ degrees of freedom to find the 95% CI $(9.30, 15.05).$

```
t.test(x)

        One Sample t-test

data:  x
t = 10.027, df = 7, p-value = 2.101e-05
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
  9.303956 15.046044
sample estimates:
mean of x 
   12.175
```

The CI does not contain 0, and the null hypothesis $H_0: \mu = 0$ is
overwhelmingly rejected because of the tiny p-value.

**Estimating the population variance and SD:** You could also get a 95% CI for $\sigma^2,$ using the
chi-squared distribution: $(n-1)S^2/\sigma^2 \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(7).$
A 95% CI for $\sigma^2$ is $(7S^2/U,\, 7S^2/L),$ where $L$ and $U$ cut
2.5% of the area from the lower and upper tails, respectively, of 
$\mathsf{Chisq}(7).$ Then take square roots of the endpoints to get a 95% CI for
$\sigma,$ which is $(2.27, 6.99).$

```
sqrt(7*var(x)/qchisq(c(.975,.025), 7))
[1] 2.270589 6.989485
```

The following session from Minitab software (somewhat edited for relevance)
gives essentially the same CI for $\sigma:$

```
MTB > OneVariance 'x';
SUBC>   Confidence 95.0.

Test and CI for One Variance: x 

Method

The chi-square method is only for the normal distribution.

Statistics

Variable  N  StDev  Variance
x         8   3.43      11.8

95% Confidence Interval

                         CI for        CI for
Variable  Method          StDev       Variance
x         Chi-Square  (2.27, 6.99)  (5.2, 48.9)
```

Neither Student's t distribution nor the chi-squared distribution is useful
for finding $P(X \ge 20).$ Each is relevant for making a confidence
interval for one of the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma.$

---

*Addendum:* Everything works better for large samples. Consider the distribution $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 12, \sigma = 3.4),$ for which
$P(Y \ge 20) = 0.0111.$

```
1 - pnorm(20, 12, 3.5)
[1] 0.01113549
```

If I generate a random sample of size $n = 800$ from this distribution the
proportion of observations that are 20 or greater is 0.02, not far from 0.0111.$

```
y = rnorm(800, 12, 3.5)
mean(y >= 20)
[1] 0.02
```

If I pretend I don't know $\mu$ and $\sigma,$ I get respective estimates
$\bar Y = 12.22$ and $S = 3.53,$ which are reasonably close to the truth.

```
mean(y);  sd(y)
[1] 12.22147
[1] 3.525766
```

The estimated normal distribution gives $P(Y \ge 20) \approx 0.013.$

```
1 - pnorm(20, mean(y), sd(y))
[1] 0.01368513
```

The 95th percentile of the true distribution is $17.76.$

```
qnorm(.95, 12, 3.5)
[1] 17.75699
```

The 95th percentile of the estimated distribution is $18.02.$

```
qnorm(.95, mean(y), sd(y))
[1] 18.02084
```

The 95th percentile of the points sampled from the true distribution is $18.15.$

```
quantile(y, .95)
     95% 
18.15345
```

A 95% t confidence interval for $\mu$  is $(11.98, 12.47)$ [no output shown,
but trust me on this], which closely brackets the true mean $\mu = 12$ of
the distribution that produced the data.

And finally, the density function of $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 12, \sigma = 3.4),$
is pretty well matched by a histogram of the $n = 800$ sampled observations.

[image]

None of these matches have been perfect, but I hope you can see that the ideas
of your problem work a *lot better* for sample size $n = 800$ than for
$n = 8.$

*Note:* I could probably have shown an example with better matches if I had
generated a dozen samples of size $n = 800$ and picked the 'best' one. But what you see here
is the first sample that came up. Also, I guess it's obvious that
an example with $n=80,000$ would have worked better yet.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. The answer in the book is exactly those you provided above. I was very confused about how and when one should use the t-distribution instead of the normal. Now I understand better. Thanks again.